# Linux screen has rough textures/patches

Tags: linux, display, ubuntu-19.10

Just to be clear my screen is okay. I have a dual booted laptop and sometimes when I log into Linux(Pop_OS 19.10) I get such a display [[image: _][1]]

I don't know what the problem is and sometimes it just fixes itself when the system goes to sleep or just randomly (I didn't notice when it gets fixed to be honest) But today it is just not going away... it's been more than an hour

> I don't even know how to phrase the problem so literally any sort of help is appreciated

Comment: It looks to me that X may be using 8 bit color.

Comment: @davidgo I did not understand. What is X?